# ping communication between interfaces in linux

Tags: linux, routes, ip, ping

Part 1 - 
Is it possible to ping between ip on port0 to ip on port1 of same NIC adapter ?
The ICMP should traverse on the wire connected between ports.
i.e

```
   On HOST A with two-port-adapter
   port-0-adapterA ---- ping-icmp-to ---- port-1-adapterA
```

Part 2 -
Is it possible to ping between ip on port0(first-adapter) to ip on port0(second-adapter) on the SAME system ? Same ICMP should traverse on the wire connected between ports.
i.e

```
   On SAME HOST A with two single-port-adapters
   port-0-adapterA ---- ping-icmp-to ---- port-0-adapterB
```

condition -

```
   ICMP should traverse physically on the wire connected between ports.
```

What kind of LINUX ip/route commands do we need to set to get this ?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: just did. Thanks

Comment: Can you please delete this version of your Q as cross-posting on stackexchange is not considered good form. Good luck with your Q!

Comment: I found The solution at below link by (Steve Kehlet) https://serverfault.com/questions/127636/force-local-ip-traffic-to-an-external-interface

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to ping between ip on port0 to ip on port1 of same NIC adapter ?

Yes and no. Normally, your IP stack routes the ICMP echo request internally (loopback), so you can ping and receive but the request and the response don't go over the wire. If you persuade the stack to physically send the request the response will come over the wire as well. (I'm assuming port0 and port1 are separate ports on a dual NIC.)

> Is it possible to ping between ip on port0(first-adapter) to ip on port0(second-adapter) on the SAME system ?

This is the exact same. Whether there are two ports on a single card or two separate cards makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution as below link -

```
      https://serverfault.com/questions/127636/force-local-ip-traffic-to-an-external-interface
```

I also verified that the packet traverse on the wire too using a sniffer.
During experiments I found that the set-arp is very much necessary to register for arp to complete. ALSO; This do not work on older RHEL version of 6.4, 6.6 but works nicely in 6.9,7 (probably due to older iptables)